# Match name and change data set to wide format in r

Tags: r, matching

I have two df like this:

```
Name1            Task   Bond    Goal    Name2          Rapport  Client
Abigail Adkins   24     20       25     Adam Tharkur    4.08    4.29
Abigail Brusse   25     26       24     Adam Tharkur    6.08    6
Adam Tharker     24     24       24     Anne Corinne    5.5     6.29
Adriel Parks     27     18       26     Alan Hamaoui    7       6.43
Allison Mofsky   21     28       20     Alyssa Sorrells 5.67    5.29
```

df1 has Name1, Task, Bond and Goal, df2 has Name2, Rapport and Client. 
My goal is to select the Names that are the same in two dfs, and have their five scores like this:

```
Name   Task     Bond     Goal    Rapport1   Client1  Rapport2   Client2
Adam    24      24       24      4.08       4.29     6.08       6
```

Each name might have multiple observations (less than 10) like "Adam", and I only want to match the first name in selection, because some I have not entered the last name. Do someone have any ideas? Thank you a lot.

Reproducible data:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="Name1,Task,Bond,Goal,Name2,Rapport,Client
Abigail Adkins,24,20,25,Adam Tharkur,4.08,4.29
Abigail Brusse,25,26,24,Adam Tharkur,6.08,6
Adam Tharker,24,24,24,Anne Corinne,5.5,6.29
Adriel Parks,27,18,26,Alan Hamaoui,7,6.43
Allison Mofsky,21,28,20,Alyssa Sorrells,5.67,5.29",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df1 <- dat[1:4]
df2 <- dat[5:7]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df1 <- dat[1:4]`and `df2 <- dat[5:7]`?

Comment: Also, do you have multiple ocurrencies of a name in `df1`, or only in `df2`? And is `Tharker` different from `Tharkur` on purpose? Because then you'd have to match every Adam.

Comment: Is it on purpose you have "Tharker" in df1 and "Tharkur" in df2? On thatt aspect, I'm unsure what "I only want to match the first name in seletion" means....

Comment: Thank you @Molx , That was a data entry error. Because the data is so large, so there are entry errors on the last name. That is why I only use the first name. Thanks!

Comment: @Dominic Comtois That was a data entry error. Because the data is so large, so there are entry errors on the last name. That is why I only use the first name. Thanks!

Comment: I see. But that can be very problematic, because even if those two are the same, how will you differentiate other Adams? You have Abigail Adkins and Brusse, for example.

Comment: That can be only due to entry errors in my sample:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'first names' can be extracted using `sub`, `merge` the two dataset by the 'Name' column, create a sequence index ('indx') for the grouping variable ('Name1'), and use `reshape` to change the format from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
df1$Name1 <- sub(' .*$', '', df1$Name1)
df2$Name2 <- sub(' .*$', '', df2$Name2)
dfN <- merge(df1, df2, by.x='Name1', by.y='Name2')
dfN$indx <- with(dfN, ave(seq_along(Name1), Name1, FUN=seq_along))
reshape(dfN, idvar=c('Name1', 'Task', 'Bond', 'Goal'), 
             timevar='indx', direction='wide')
#   Name1 Task Bond Goal Rapport.1 Client.1 Rapport.2 Client.2
#1  Adam   24   24   24      4.08     4.29      6.08        6
```

Or we can use the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v1.9.5.  Instructions for installing it are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Remove the 'last name' in the 'Name' columns of both dataset (as showed above), then convert the 'df1' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), and set the key column as 'Name1' (`setkey(.., Name1)`).  Join with 'df2', create a sequence column ('N') for the 'Name1', and use `dcast`.  In the devel version, the `dcast` can take multiple `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setkey(setDT(df1), Name1)[df2, nomatch=0][, N:=1:.N, Name1],
             ...~N, value.var= c('Rapport', 'Client'))
#    Name1 Task Bond Goal 1_Rapport 2_Rapport 1_Client 2_Client
#1:  Adam   24   24   24      4.08      6.08     4.29        6
```

Comment: Could you explan the dfN$indx line?  Is it adding a sequential number for each row so that timevar in reshape does something?  Thank you, akrun.

Comment: @lawyeR Yes, it is adding a sequential number for the group 'Name1' so that it can be used for the `reshape` line.